# What is the recommended way to use memoize?

Tags: clojure

I have occasionally used `memoize` function. In usually the following form:

```
(defn- sqrt-denom [iterations]
  (/ 1 (if (= iterations 0)
         2
         (+ 2 (sqrt-denom (dec iterations))))))

(def sqrt-denom (memoize sqrt-denom))
```

I assumed that it is "proper" to reuse the function name when memoizing. Is this a good practice? Or should I use different names for the non-memoized and memoized functions?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to give the non-memoized version a name at all? `(def sqrt-denom (memoize (fn [iterations] ...)))`

Comment: I'd be careful having a "permanently" memorized top level `def` though. If your program runs for a long time and that function is exposed to many different inputs, the memorization map can get huge. Of course that's a trade off when dealing with memorization, but I'd make sure a local memorized version doesn't suffice first.

Comment: I don’t think there is any problem with your technique though, similar example in the Clojure docs: https://clojure.org/reference/atoms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would never re-use the name of a top-level `def`, especially when self-referencing.  Two choices:

```
(defn ^:no-doc sqrt-denom-impl [iterations]
  (/ 1 (if (= iterations 0)
         2
         (+ 2 (sqrt-denom (dec iterations))))))

(def sqrt-denom (memoize sqrt-denom-impl))
```

or even simpler:

```
(def sqrt-denom
  (memoize (fn  [iterations]
    (/ 1 (if (= iterations 0)
           2
           (+ 2 (sqrt-denom (dec iterations))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Alan Thompson, I've often used `(def sqrt-denom (memoize (fn ...)))`, but it's awkward to split a simple `defn` into a `def` and `fn` just to wrap the latter. The syntactic transformation makes it difficult to switch back and forth between the memoized and the unmemoized versions of the function, and `memoize` is the one function that made me wish Clojure had something like Python decorators.

Then, recently, I discovered that Clojure does have decorators:

```
(defn sqrt-denom ...)

(alter-var-root #'sqrt-denom memoize)
```

This is very similar to your example, but it avoids the confusion of two vars named the same thing, and it clearly states the author's intent. This is now my preferred method for memoizing functions.

Comment: Yeah, eg Leiningen uses this technique [with some frequency](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/search?q=alter-var-root). The unmemoized `defn` can be quite handy during development.